# Need to create client using svcutil but get error message Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

I am attempting to create WCF client files using the svcutil.exe.  I run my wpf app that is hosting my wcf service library.  I get the following error when running svcutil from visual studio command prompt 2010:

WS-Metadata Exchange Error
URI: net.tcp://localhost:50100/duplex
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'net.tcp://localhost:50100/duplex'.

Can someone explain what is wrong with my configuration file, and how I can successfully generate my client files using svcutil.exe?

Here is my svcutil command (I run this command after starting my service of course):

c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC>svcutil.exe net.tcp://localhost:50100/duplex /d:c:\temp

Here is my app.config for wpf application hosting the wcf service library:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="baseAddress" value="net.tcp://localhost:50100/duplex"/>
    </appSettings>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <!--<bindings />-->
        <client />
        <services>
            <service name="TrackRejectCommunication.RejectService"
                 behaviorConfiguration="RejectServiceBehavior">
                <endpoint address=""
                      binding="netTcpBinding"
                      bindingConfiguration="DuplexNetTcpBinding_IRejectService"
                      name="netTcp"
                      contract="TrackRejectCommunication.IRejectService" />
                <endpoint name="NetTcpMetadataPoint"
                      address="mexTcp"
                      binding="mexTcpBinding"
                      contract="IMetadataExchange" />
                <host>
                     <baseAddresses>
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>
            </service>
        </services>
        <bindings>
            <netTcpBinding>
                <binding name="DuplexNetTcpBinding_IRejectService"
                     sendTimeout="00:00:10"
                     portSharingEnabled="false">                       
                  </binding>   
            </netTcpBinding>            
        </bindings> 
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="RejectServiceBehavior">
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetUrl="http://localhost:50103/Metadata/Duplex" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"
                      sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

I get the base address via the configuration manager in my wpf application.  The I use the following code to start the service in my wpf application:

```
RejectService rejectService = new RejectService();
//start the reject service.
HostStartup.StartService(rejectService);
```

The StartService code:

```
Uri baseAddress = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["baseAddress"]);

//Instantiate new ServiceHost with the singleton instance being passed in
myServiceHost = new ServiceHost(instance, baseAddress);


        //Open myServiceHost
        myServiceHost.Open();
```

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong but couldn't you use `http://localhost:50100/duplex` If you rightclick your svc and click show in browser, is it the same what is says as what your trying to do?

Comment: I have learned that the svcutil.exe is not always the best way to go when trying to create a wcf client from service files.  I decided to just add a service resource to my client using my http service address.  This created the generated client file for me.

Comment: I think you mean `Service Reference` but I get your point. I've never used the svcutil, because adding the service reference in via Visual Studio itself works perfectly. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem when using svcutil to create wsdl/proxy for a singleton service started via "myServiceHost = new ServiceHost(instance, baseAddress);".  I was able to work around the problem by temporarily commenting out the code that created/opened the ServiceHost instance, then running svcutil to create the wsdl, then restoring the code to it's original format.  It appears that whatever svcutil is doing is incompatible with the in-code instantiated ServiceHost.

For reference, the particular error that I encountered was:

Warning: There was an error loading the service type to be exported: ...

Details:The type initializer for ... threw an exception.